# Why royalties are can't be enforced in smart contracts? Can ERC-3475 solve the issue?

Tags: tokens, nft

Blockchains are unable to enforce stipulations on smart contracts, so NFT royalties are optional for buyers, and it depends on the NFT marketplace to execute the royalties for artists. Does it mean that royalties can't be put on chain?

Also, since ERC-3475 enables complicated metadata input, does it solve the royalty problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to enforce NFT royalties at the smart contract level since it would impossible to know which NFT transfers are the result of sales, and which are merely wallets moving or consolidating their NFTs. NFT royalties is a known problem in the NFT space, and there is already a standard exploring around that which is [ERC-2981](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981). ERC-2981 enables optional NFT royalties to be paid onchain at the smart contract level.

To answer the second part of your question, I don't think ERC-3475 would be the answer here, and I don't think it is even relevant to the problem of NFT royalties.